# Should I use XML or JSON as a data format in Android Applications?

Tags: xml, android, json

I'm starting to develop an application for Google Android and heavily relying on a web API that can deliver data in a restful way via json or xml. I now have to decide which library to choose.

I saw that google includes org.json classes in the API but haven't tested them yet.

How are your experiences? What library/API should I use and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're mostly aiming for an internal API that is simply a link between servers you control and a client you're creating, I'd highly recommend JSON - it's far more concise in most cases, thus minimizing the data transfer necessary.

Parsing JSON with org.json is as straightforward as passing the JSON string to the constructor of [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), and then using the appropriate type get-methods on each of your expected attributes.

Comment: Is the simplicity json gives you more useful for generating the web back end or for the handset? The most important thing for me is to write the android client in a very fast and simple way. The back end offers both already

Comment: Well, the argument I was mostly making didn't have to do with either, but more the data link in between; however JSON can be nice and straightforward to parse and use (though there are some nice XML libraries too). In general, for known formats JSON will most likely be slightly faster to parse simply due to its conciseness, but in all but the most data-intensive apps this probably won't be a noticeable difference in speed.

Comment: I'm now using Json and playing arround with google-gson for parsing

Comment: Please keep in mind that JSON is only smaller if the tags are longer than the data. If you are sending more data than you send tags then they are about the same and you would have been better off using XML for the fast parsing speeds. I would also argue that people expect slow mobile load times and fast app running times so try and not slow down the app time by using a slower format to parse.

Comment: @Amber: I am pretty sure that is only true for small files. For larger files it becomes apparent that XML only needs a single pass and I think most JSON is multipass (though I could be wrong there).

Comment: @RobertMassaioli JSON can easily be parsed in a single pass.

Comment: @Amber: Well in that case the blog I read yesterday was wrong. I just did even more searching of the internals of the JSON implementations and it turns out that you can. In that case the choice becomes rather arbitrary unless you are forced to choose one or the other for some reason; thats good to know.

Comment: I now use json whenever possible in my Android Apps. It is faster to download and with the jacksson parser library it seems also to be faster to parse.