# Android which type of feed is faster for rendering?

Tags: android, xml, json

Currently, I've developed android news application for my client. In this project, I've used JSON feed for content sync but I feel rendering JSON feed in android is a bit slow. Perhaps, due to my coding or something else. Now want to try XML feed instead of JSON.

Thus please let me know which type of feed (between XML and JSon.. but let me know any good feed any other else) is faster for rendering in Android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316966/should-i-use-xml-or-json-as-a-data-format-in-android-applications?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is definitely faster and easier to use too. You don't need another XML parser and tons of code either. It's as easy as:

```
JSONObject json_data=new JSONObject(http_result);
String name=json_data.get("name");
```

Comment: I back this answer. JSON is smaller in size, thus faster to load and parse. Once parsed, the rest of the process will require exactly the same amount of time as for XML.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Speaking JSON Parsing is Lightweight and faster.

But if you want to try XML Parsing try using XMLPull Parser (Is the Most Efficient Xml parser and also recommended by Google )

Answer (score 1):

I second JSON as a feed format because it's lighter. I'd like to make a suggestion on how you can make the parsing seem faster.

Maybe your parsing is slow because the JSON response you are parsing is extremely large. I assume that your feed is a JSON Array. What you can do is do the parsing in an `AsyncTask`. In the `doInBackGround()`, call `publishProgress()` and update your UI whenever you parse one feed item(or a batch of feed items).

This way, even if your JSON parsing takes time, it will seem like it's much faster to the user.